# Webform streaming live video in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms, video-streaming

So I have a windows app that saves each frame from an IP camera.  Well it saves to the same file and each new image overwrites the last.  Now I have a webform that displays this image, but I have to press a button to display the new image.  Here is the code for that:

```
namespace PlayVideo

public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    FileStream fs = File.Open(@"location of filestream");



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string saveTo = @"place to save";
        FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);

        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/OrangeLogo.jpg";
        Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/test.jpg";


    }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream) 
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte [] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer,0,Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while( bytesRead > 0 ) 
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer,0,Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }

    protected void StartBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite(@"location of writestream");
        FileStream readStream = File.Open(@"location of readstream");

        ReadWriteStream(readStream, writeStream);
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/test.jpg";

    }



}
```

The code for the ReadWriteStream() is from 
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4669/save-a-stream-to-a-file/

So my question is, how can I display the new image without pressing the button?  Is this possible?  Oh and I have to use VS2010 because it is for work and they only have VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a viewer page to show the image and put this tag:

<img src="/video.aspx" id="the-image"/>

Then on the same page you can add a javascript to refresh the image:

```
function refreshImage(){
    $("#the-image").attr('src', 'video.aspx');
    setTimeout("refreshImage();", 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout("refreshImage();", 5000);
})
```

Then you need to change your video.aspx to spit the image:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.TransmitFile(imagePath);
}
```

You might need to refine this code to make this work, but you get the idea..

Comment: Do I get rid of what I had in my Page_Load function and only have what you put?  I did that and put what you have exactly, because I am new to webforms and not good with javascript.  I wanted to see what it does; it just goes to the viewer page and never refreshes the image.  I will continue to try to work with what you gave because I feel like it's close.  If you have any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Comment: does the javascript code refresh the page_load function? because that is where I save the latest image.